# Setting current date as default on calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datepicker, marketo

I have selected the date field in Marketo and it uses a calender for you to select a desired date.

I would like this filed to be defaulted to "todays" date unless changed by the user?

Can this be done? I was trying `FieldID = {{system.date}}`

But is doesnt seem to input the current date in the field unless you select it through the calender

Comment: could you please provide the link for *marketo* lib or framework?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example script you can use in Marketo to output today's date as a token:

```
## Access Velocity's calendar object
#set($x = $date.calendar)

## Format date
#set($current_date = $date.format('dd-MM-yyyy', $x.getTime()))

## Returns today's date
$current_date
```

Please see the [Marketo's developer documentation](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/email-scripting/) for more information about using token scripting.